# Interpretation of dummy variables with quadratic interaction

Tags: regression, panel-data

I am having a little trouble interpreting group dummy variables. I am analyzing the effect of the debt to GDP ratio (debtgdp) and squared debt-to-GDP ratio (debtgdp2) on economic growth (g).

I want to see if there is a difference across Advanced Economies (AE), Emerging Markets (EM) and Least Developed Countries (LDC). Therefore I created dummies and set AE as reference group. Then I multiplied the dummy with the debt-to-GDP ratio:

e.g.:

```
generate LDC = group==3
generate LDCdebtgdp = LDC*debtgdp
generate LDCdebtgdp2 = LDC*debtgd
```

The output:

```
debtgdp -.01033349     
debtgdp2    -.00233946     
LDCdebtgdp  .03394691   
EMdebtgdp   .00045469     
AEdebtgdp   (omitted)     
LDCdebtgdp2 -.00977115     
EMdebtgdp2  .00278833     
AEdebtgdp2  (omitted)
```

Interpreting: `debtgdp` has a negative effect on economic growth and the negative sign of `debtgdp2` would indicate a convex relationship. (I don’t want to worry about significance for now).
Now how do I interpret both dummy interactions?

Is it correct to say that the negative debt-to-GDP effect is lower for EM and LDC than it is for the reference group? And how about the convexity? Since LDCdebtgdp2 is negative, would it mean that the estimation is even more convex for LDC than it is for AE?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think what you are saying at the end is correct.  With the model that you have estimated, the effect of `debtgdp` for `AE` countries is given by the coefficients on `debtgdp` and `debtgdp^2`.  For `LDC` countries, the effect is given by `(debtgdp + LDCdebtgdp)` and `(debtgdp^2 + LDCdebtgdp^2)`; and a similar result holds for `EM` countries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wasn't sure if debtgdp in that model actually gave me the AE specific effect.

I wish you a happy new year! Thanks!